# Should I split these services into their own module?

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

I am considering breaking a large ZF2 module in to two separate modules and I'm not sure how to handle the service layer.

The current module has a service layer and a domain.  The domain objects closely model business concepts and include a subset related to financial accounting.  It's these accounting objects which I am considering moving to their own module.

The new accounting module would define interfaces such as iAccountable, iLedgerSource, iStatementSource, and these would be implemented by objects in the existing 'core' domain.

My question is two-fold: should I be concerned about the 'core' domain being dependent on another module?, i.e. the accounting module?  (I don't think so, as I can't see an easy way around it).

Secondly, should I leave the service layer in the existing module, or put it in a module of its own?, i.e. a 'services' module?  (I think probably the latter).

Comment: From the `domain-driven-design` tag you chose: "Note that conceptual DDD questions are better to be asked at programmers.stackexchange.com."

Answer (score 1):

### Domain module & domain interface module

If I understand correctly, you're about to create a "domain interface" module. While this is not wrong, I don't see the benefit of having a [Separated Interface](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html) for domain modules.

So the cleanest option you have is to move the interfaces into the domain module. **Note that this requires that you don't have dependencies from the domain to other modules.** You should place the domain module at the "center" of your layer design, because in DDD, the domain is the most important part of the software.

See also [Clean Architecture](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) for an architecture that supports DDD well.

### Service module

You should definitely separate the service module from the domain module. They have different concerns: The service module contains the use case logic, the domain module the domain logic.

If, for example, you need a new interface to your application (let's say a web service), then you just create a new service module for that - the domain module can be reused.

Comment: Hi Dmi, I am planning to split the Domain across two modules - one 'Core' and one 'Accounting'.  The Core module would implement interfaces from the Accounting module.  I will separate out the Service layer as you suggest.